# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended - Oracle SQL error

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle

I am trying to run a SELECT query against an Oracle DB using the oracledb Node.js module.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
        gcc.concatenated_segments Code_combination,
        SUM (NVL(gb.begin_balance_dr,
        0) - NVL(gb.begin_balance_cr,
        0)) beginning_bal,
        SUM (NVL(gb.begin_balance_dr,
        0) - NVL(gb.begin_balance_cr,
        0) (NVL(gb.period_net_Dr,
        0) - NVL(gb.period_net_cr,
        0))) end_bal 
    FROM
        gl_balances gb,
        gl_code_combinations_kfv gcc 
    WHERE
        gb.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id 
        AND gcc.CONCATENATED_SEGMENTS = '01-000-2990-0000-000' 
        AND gb.ledger_id  = 1 
        AND gb.Actual_flag = 'A' 
        AND gb.period_name = 'Nov-16' 
        AND gb.currency_code = (
            SELECT
                currency_code 
            FROM
                gl_ledgers 
            WHERE
                ledger_id = gb.ledger_id 
        ) 
    GROUP BY
        gcc.concatenated_segments;
```

Could someone point out where I'm going wrong with this query, I can't see anything wrong with it! I can post the whole code sample if that would help but it seems to be an issue with the SQL.

Comment: I have a different tool with a problem ending with `;`, try to remove the `;`

Comment: some algebra sign is missing before `(NVL(gb.period_net_Dr,` in 8th line.

Comment: Correct, also removing the `;` as suggested by @user7294900 made it work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some algebra:

```
SELECT
    gcc.concatenated_segments Code_combination,  <--- You need a comma separating these two
    SUM (NVL(gb.begin_balance_dr,
    0) - NVL(gb.begin_balance_cr,
    0)) beginning_bal,
    SUM (NVL(gb.begin_balance_dr,
    0) - NVL(gb.begin_balance_cr,
    0) (NVL(gb.period_net_Dr,      <---- And you need a subtraction sign before NVL here
    0) - NVL(gb.period_net_cr,
    0))) end_bal 
FROM ...
```

Comment: Concatenated_segments means "Code_combination" in oracle E Business Suite, which the OP didn't tag.

Comment: I needed to use `gcc.concatenated_segments as Code_combination` as well as some of the advice from the other suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` definitely has a syntax error, on the line marked below.

If you write your code neatly, you are more likely to avoid such errors:

```
SELECT gcc.concatenated_segments as Code_combination,
       SUM(NVL(gb.begin_balance_dr, 0) -
           NVL(gb.begin_balance_cr, 0)
          ) as beginning_bal,
       SUM(NVL(gb.begin_balance_dr, 0) -
           NVL(gb.begin_balance_cr, 0) -  -- this is a guess
           (NVL(gb.period_net_Dr, 0) -
            NVL(gb.period_net_cr, 0)
           )
          ) as end_bal
```

There may be other errors in your code.

Comment: You are correct - there was some missing algebra on that line. I also had to take advice from other comments

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for all the comments. By taking on-board all your feedback I was able to get a result back from the database. Here is my SQL that is working:

```
SELECT
        gcc.concatenated_segments as Code_combination,
        SUM (NVL(gb.begin_balance_dr,
        0) - NVL(gb.begin_balance_cr,
        0)) as beginning_bal,
        SUM (NVL(gb.begin_balance_dr,
        0) - NVL(gb.begin_balance_cr,
        0) - (NVL(gb.period_net_Dr,
        0) - NVL(gb.period_net_cr,
        0)))as end_bal 
    FROM
        gl_balances gb,
        gl_code_combinations_kfv gcc 
    WHERE
        gb.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id 
        AND gcc.CONCATENATED_SEGMENTS = '01-000-2990-0000-000' 
        AND gb.ledger_id  = 1 
        AND gb.Actual_flag = 'A' 
        AND gb.period_name = 'Nov-16' 
        AND gb.currency_code = (
            SELECT
                currency_code 
            FROM
                gl_ledgers 
            WHERE
                ledger_id = gb.ledger_id 
        ) 
    GROUP BY
        gcc.concatenated_segments
```

Thanks everyone!